# mysql how to set column default value during a sql run

Tags: mysql, import, default-value

for a database with 100 tables, and all tables have a column named "country varchar(20) not null". Right now we have a big SQL file that was dumped a while ago and all the tables do not have country column.

```
mysql -u root -p newDatabase < dump_sql_file.sql
```

How to set the default column value country="US" while running the command above?

changing table schema

```
country varchar(20) not null default "US"
```

not acceptable, because the database is alive and being used by others.

The hard way is to change the SQL file, adding the country column for every create and insert commands. That is what we want to avoid. Is there any tools like sql parser that allows user to manipulate SQL files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although it would make `INSERT`s a bit slower, one way to do it would be to write `BEFORE INSERT` triggers for tables that have `country` column and set the value before a row gets inserted.

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)'s the documentation for `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.